# Ansible dictionary parameters are treated as string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, pytest

The following python script(At Reference-2) is invoked by ansible(at Reference-1),
It results in the following error at python,
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Can you help in identifying the issue ?

Reference-1

```
     - name: Get IPs for non-vlan testing ports
    testing_port_ip_facts:

    testing_ports_id: "{{testing_ports_id}}"

    dut_switch_ports: "{{dut_switch_ports}}"

    minigraph_bgp: "{{minigraph_bgp}}"

    minigraph_neighbors: "{{minigraph_neighbors}}"

    delegate_to: localhost
```

Reference-2

```
    def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        testing_ports_id=dict(required=True),
        dut_switch_ports=dict(required=True),
        minigraph_bgp=dict(reguired=True),
        minigraph_neighbors=dict(reguired=True),
    ),
    supports_check_mode=True
)

m_args = module.params
testing_ports_id = m_args['testing_ports_id']
dut_switch_ports = m_args['dut_switch_ports']
minigraph_bgp = m_args['minigraph_bgp']
minigraph_neighbors = m_args['minigraph_neighbors']

testing_ports_ip = {}

for port_id in testing_ports_id:
    for peer in minigraph_bgp:
        if peer['name'] == minigraph_neighbors[dut_switch_ports[int(port_id)]]['name'] and netaddr.valid_ipv4(peer['addr']):
            testing_ports_ip[port_id] = peer['addr']
            break

module.exit_json(ansible_facts={'testing_ports_ip': testing_ports_ip})
```

'''

Source : https://github.com/Azure/sonic-mgmt/blob/master/ansible/library/testing_port_ip_facts.py

Variable contents :

"testing_ports_id : ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30'] "

"minigraph_neighgbors : {'Ethernet8': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA03T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet0': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA01T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet4': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA02T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1     '}, 'Ethernet108': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA12T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet100': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA10T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet104': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA11T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}     , 'Ethernet68': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA02T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet96': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA09T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet124': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA16T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'E     thernet92': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA08T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet120': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA15T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet52': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA14T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ether     net56': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA15T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet76': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA04T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet72': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA03T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet64     ': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA01T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet32': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA09T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet16': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA05T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet36': {'     namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA10T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet12': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA04T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet88': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA07T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet116': {'name     space': '', 'name': 'ARISTA14T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet80': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA05T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet112': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA13T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet84': {'namespac     e': '', 'name': 'ARISTA06T0', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet48': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA13T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet44': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA12T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet40': {'namespace': '     ', 'name': 'ARISTA11T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet28': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA08T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet60': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA16T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet20': {'namespace': '', 'n     ame': 'ARISTA06T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}, 'Ethernet24': {'namespace': '', 'name': 'ARISTA07T2', 'port': 'Ethernet1'}} "

"minigraph_bgp : [{'peer_addr': '10.0.0.0', 'addr': '10.0.0.1', 'name': 'ARISTA01T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.10', 'addr': '10.0.0.11', 'name': 'ARISTA06T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.12', 'addr': '10.0.0.13', 'name'     : 'ARISTA07T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.14', 'addr': '10.0.0.15', 'name': 'ARISTA08T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.16', 'addr': '10.0.0.17', 'name': 'ARISTA09T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.18', 'addr     ': '10.0.0.19', 'name': 'ARISTA10T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.20', 'addr': '10.0.0.21', 'name': 'ARISTA11T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.22', 'addr': '10.0.0.23', 'name': 'ARISTA12T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_add     r': '10.0.0.24', 'addr': '10.0.0.25', 'name': 'ARISTA13T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.26', 'addr': '10.0.0.27', 'name': 'ARISTA14T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.28', 'addr': '10.0.0.29', 'name': 'ARISTA15T2', 'as     n': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.2', 'addr': '10.0.0.3', 'name': 'ARISTA02T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.30', 'addr': '10.0.0.31', 'name': 'ARISTA16T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.32', 'addr': '10.0.0.33', 'name     ': 'ARISTA01T0', 'asn': 64001}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.34', 'addr': '10.0.0.35', 'name': 'ARISTA02T0', 'asn': 64002}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.36', 'addr': '10.0.0.37', 'name': 'ARISTA03T0', 'asn': 64003}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.38', 'add     r': '10.0.0.39', 'name': 'ARISTA04T0', 'asn': 64004}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.40', 'addr': '10.0.0.41', 'name': 'ARISTA05T0', 'asn': 64005}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.42', 'addr': '10.0.0.43', 'name': 'ARISTA06T0', 'asn': 64006}, {'peer_ad     dr': '10.0.0.44', 'addr': '10.0.0.45', 'name': 'ARISTA07T0', 'asn': 64007}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.46', 'addr': '10.0.0.47', 'name': 'ARISTA08T0', 'asn': 64008}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.48', 'addr': '10.0.0.49', 'name': 'ARISTA09T0', 'a     sn': 64009}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.4', 'addr': '10.0.0.5', 'name': 'ARISTA03T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.50', 'addr': '10.0.0.51', 'name': 'ARISTA10T0', 'asn': 64010}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.52', 'addr': '10.0.0.53', 'nam     e': 'ARISTA11T0', 'asn': 64011}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.54', 'addr': '10.0.0.55', 'name': 'ARISTA12T0', 'asn': 64012}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.56', 'addr': '10.0.0.57', 'name': 'ARISTA13T0', 'asn': 64013}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.58', 'ad     dr': '10.0.0.59', 'name': 'ARISTA14T0', 'asn': 64014}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.60', 'addr': '10.0.0.61', 'name': 'ARISTA15T0', 'asn': 64015}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.62', 'addr': '10.0.0.63', 'name': 'ARISTA16T0', 'asn': 64016}, {'peer_a     ddr': '10.0.0.6', 'addr': '10.0.0.7', 'name': 'ARISTA04T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': '10.0.0.8', 'addr': '10.0.0.9', 'name': 'ARISTA05T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::11', 'addr': 'FC00::12', 'name': 'ARISTA05T2', 'asn':      65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::15', 'addr': 'FC00::16', 'name': 'ARISTA06T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::19', 'addr': 'FC00::1A', 'name': 'ARISTA07T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::1D', 'addr': 'FC00::1E', 'name': 'ARIS     TA08T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::1', 'addr': 'FC00::2', 'name': 'ARISTA01T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::21', 'addr': 'FC00::22', 'name': 'ARISTA09T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::25', 'addr': 'FC00::26',      'name': 'ARISTA10T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::29', 'addr': 'FC00::2A', 'name': 'ARISTA11T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::2D', 'addr': 'FC00::2E', 'name': 'ARISTA12T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::31', 'ad     dr': 'FC00::32', 'name': 'ARISTA13T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::35', 'addr': 'FC00::36', 'name': 'ARISTA14T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::39', 'addr': 'FC00::3A', 'name': 'ARISTA15T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr':      'FC00::3D', 'addr': 'FC00::3E', 'name': 'ARISTA16T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::41', 'addr': 'FC00::42', 'name': 'ARISTA01T0', 'asn': 64001}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::45', 'addr': 'FC00::46', 'name': 'ARISTA02T0', 'asn': 64002     }, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::49', 'addr': 'FC00::4A', 'name': 'ARISTA03T0', 'asn': 64003}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::4D', 'addr': 'FC00::4E', 'name': 'ARISTA04T0', 'asn': 64004}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::51', 'addr': 'FC00::52', 'name': 'ARISTA05T     0', 'asn': 64005}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::55', 'addr': 'FC00::56', 'name': 'ARISTA06T0', 'asn': 64006}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::59', 'addr': 'FC00::5A', 'name': 'ARISTA07T0', 'asn': 64007}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::5D', 'addr': 'FC00::5E', 'n     ame': 'ARISTA08T0', 'asn': 64008}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::5', 'addr': 'FC00::6', 'name': 'ARISTA02T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::61', 'addr': 'FC00::62', 'name': 'ARISTA09T0', 'asn': 64009}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::65', 'addr':      'FC00::66', 'name': 'ARISTA10T0', 'asn': 64010}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::69', 'addr': 'FC00::6A', 'name': 'ARISTA11T0', 'asn': 64011}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::6D', 'addr': 'FC00::6E', 'name': 'ARISTA12T0', 'asn': 64012}, {'peer_addr': 'FC0     0::71', 'addr': 'FC00::72', 'name': 'ARISTA13T0', 'asn': 64013}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::75', 'addr': 'FC00::76', 'name': 'ARISTA14T0', 'asn': 64014}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::79', 'addr': 'FC00::7A', 'name': 'ARISTA15T0', 'asn': 64015}, {'     peer_addr': 'FC00::7D', 'addr': 'FC00::7E', 'name': 'ARISTA16T0', 'asn': 64016}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::9', 'addr': 'FC00::A', 'name': 'ARISTA03T2', 'asn': 65200}, {'peer_addr': 'FC00::D', 'addr': 'FC00::E', 'name': 'ARISTA04T2', 'asn'     : 65200}] "

"dut_switch_ports : ['Ethernet0', 'Ethernet4', 'Ethernet8', 'Ethernet12', 'Ethernet16', 'Ethernet20', 'Ethernet24', 'Ethernet28', 'Ethernet32', 'Ethernet36', 'Etherne40', 'Ethernet44', 'Ethernet48', 'Ethernet52', 'Ethernet56', 'Ether     net60', 'Ethernet64', 'Ethernet68', 'Ethernet72', 'Ethernet76', 'Ethernet80', 'Ethernet84', 'Ethernet88', 'Ethernet92', 'Ethernet96', 'Ethernet100', 'Ethernet104', 'Ethernet108', 'Ethernet112', 'Ethernet116', 'Ethernet120', 'Ethernet     124'] "

Comment: to replay and see your error, you have to show the content of different variable..{{testing_ports_id}}  and so on

Comment: I have updated the requested details. Could you please check and help if possible

Comment: you have lot of space in your key and in some value you are using..see my answer to fix your errors..

Comment: dont forget to close the question by validating the right answer...

Answer (score 2):

The error you have are comming in your differents value or different key:
(you have bad space in the key name or value)

check this task to trap errors in dut_switch_ports, minigraph_bgp and minigraph_neighbors:

```
- name: searching values dut_switch_ports
  set_fact:
    errors_dut_switch_ports: "{{ errors_dut_switch_ports | d([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ dut_switch_ports }}"
  when: '" " in item'

- name: debug errors_dut_switch_ports
  debug:
    msg: "{{ errors_dut_switch_ports }}"
  when: errors_dut_switch_ports is defined

- name: searching errors_minigraph_bgp
  set_fact:
    errors_minigraph_bgp: "{{ errors_minigraph_bgp | d([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ minigraph_bgp }}"
  when: item.peer_addr is undefined or item.addr is undefined or item.name is undefined

- name: debug errors_minigraph_bgp
  debug:
    msg: "{{ errors_minigraph_bgp }}"
  when: errors_minigraph_bgp is defined

- name: searching errors_minigraph_neighbors
  set_fact:
    errors_minigraph_neighbors: "{{ errors_minigraph_neighbors | d([]) + [{item.key: item.value}] }}"
  loop: "{{ minigraph_neighbors | dict2items}}"
  when: '" " in item.key or item.value.name is undefined or item.value.port is undefined '
  
- name: debug errors_minigraph_neighbors
  debug:
    msg: "{{ errors_minigraph_neighbors }}"
  when: errors_minigraph_neighbors is defined
```

so after fixing error in key and value, when i use your module there is again an error

you havent notify the type of args, the default is string

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        testing_ports_id=dict(type='list', required=True),
        dut_switch_ports=dict(type='list', required=True),
        minigraph_bgp=dict(type='list', reguired=True),
        minigraph_neighbors=dict(type='dict', reguired=True),
    ),
    supports_check_mode=True
```

test the playbook:

```
- name: Get IPs for non-vlan testing ports
  testing_port_ip_facts:
    testing_ports_id: "{{testing_ports_id}}"
    dut_switch_ports: "{{dut_switch_ports}}"
    minigraph_bgp: "{{minigraph_bgp}}"
    minigraph_neighbors: "{{minigraph_neighbors}}"
  register: output
- name: debug 
  debug:
    msg: "{{ output }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "testing_ports_ip": {
                "0": "10.0.0.1",
                "1": "10.0.0.3",
                "11": "10.0.0.23",
                "12": "10.0.0.25",
                "13": "10.0.0.27",
                "14": "10.0.0.29",
                "15": "10.0.0.31",
                "16": "10.0.0.33",
                "17": "10.0.0.35",
                "18": "10.0.0.37",
                "19": "10.0.0.39",
                "2": "10.0.0.5",
                "20": "10.0.0.41",
                "21": "10.0.0.43",
                "22": "10.0.0.45",
                "23": "10.0.0.47",
                "24": "10.0.0.49",
                "25": "10.0.0.51",
                "26": "10.0.0.53",
                "27": "10.0.0.55",
                "28": "10.0.0.57",
                "29": "10.0.0.59",
                "3": "10.0.0.7",
                "30": "10.0.0.61",
                "4": "10.0.0.9",
                "5": "10.0.0.11",
                "6": "10.0.0.13",
                "7": "10.0.0.15",
                "8": "10.0.0.17",
                "9": "10.0.0.19"
            }
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try and get back

Comment: its easier to debug in custom plugin than module, because your python print for debbuging are easier to read in summary tnah module